# Monitoring SQL Server 2008 with WMI

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, wmi, wmi-query

Currently I have the following query to monitor a parameter of SQL server 2008 using PowerShell.

```
SELECT cntr_value as Mem_KB 
FROM sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
WHERE counter_name = 'SQL Cache Memory (KB)'
```

I would like to monitor the same with WMI. How is it possible? What would be the corresponding WMI namespaces for it?

I have a few more commands which I want to find out the namespaces. Here are the classes of those commands...

```
sys.dm_os_performance_counters
SYS.SYSPERFINFO
sys.dm_os_sys_memory
sys.dm_os_wait_stats
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why you need WMI ?  ,when you can query those DMVS directly

Comment: That's Clients requirement... It was handled with PowerShell earlier, Now they want to use only WMI.